# Get list index out of range error, had succeeded once a time

Tags: python, xlrd, python-webbrowser

I want to build a script to read an excel and then search the value in search engine and finally output the first url in another excel.But there ara something wrong with my script.Here is my code.

```
import xlwt
import xlrd
import bs4
import webbrowser

book = xlrd.open_workbook("test_input.xls")

table = book.sheet_by_index(0)

names = table.col_values(0)

workbook = xlwt.Workbook(encoding = 'utf-8')

worksheet = workbook.add_sheet("my sheet1")

result = []
for index in range(len(names)):
    fakeua = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.84 Safari/537.36"}
    searchPage = requests.get('https://www.baidu.com/s?wd=' + names[index], headers = fakeua)
    searchSoup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(searchPage.text, features="html.parser")
    elements = searchSoup.select('.t a')
    result.append(elements[0].get('href'))
    worksheet.write(index,1,result)
workbook.save('test_result.xls')
```

I got line 23 list index out of range in cmd.I had succeeded once a time,but then I deleted the test_result.xls file and tried again. I failed , and got the same out of range error.I don't know why it is out of range. I tried to modify the code to

```
for i in range(min(1, len(elements))):
    worksheet.write(elements[i].get('href'))
```

It run smoothly.But I get nothing in the test_result.xls
Thanks for anybody who would like to give a little hint of this desperate situation.

Comment: I *think* indexes in the context of Excel spreadsheets may be base 1. Try changing to *worksheet.write(index+1,1,result)*

Comment: Thank you so much.This completely sovled my problem.The script run smoothly.

Comment: This is completely confusing me ... Since the test scrpt run soomthly, I tried the full version. And then I got the same error. Then I deleted the test_result.xls and run the test version. It broke again with the same error"line 23, in <module>
    result.append(elements[0].get('href'))
IndexError: list index out of range". I think elements[0] have value. I don't know what's going on. Anyway thanks for help.

Comment: The elements list is empty